# log4j2.xml fluentd error, when servlet throws ex log gets corrupted (dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError)

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, fluentd

I have an spring boot application which is wrapped with docker where fluentD is the log agent, when looking in kibana I get sometimes this odd message :

> dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError
> error="pattern not matched with data
> 'e","file":"FillInterest.java","line":103,"exact":true,"location":"
> ...

The corrupted log happns when error is throwen from the servlect (in scnarios such as queue consuming I can see it hapaning )

I can also see in this JSON sent to kibana an entry "error" with the same value (same value for entry log, which can easily be understood after looking in flunetd.conf )

I can't change fluentd configuration since it serve lots of other applications, so I need to change log4j2 ...

I have been struggling with that for a while,It will be super if someone can point out where the problem is
Any thoughts ?

Attached is data about my server to better understand the issue

A part from my pom.xml :

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.4.RELEASE
 

...

```
<properties>
   <java.version>11</java.version>
   <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
 </properties>
```

...

```
<dependencies>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <!-- Configuring Spring Boot to use Log4j2 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- log4j2  -->
```

in addition I have resources/log4j2-spring.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <JsonLayout complete="false" compact="true" eventEol="true" properties="true">
        <KeyValuePair key="userName" value="${ctx:userName}"/>
      </JsonLayout>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and the configurations for fluent are :

```
<system>
  log_level info
</system>

<filter **>
  @type parser
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
</filter>

<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  remove_keys log
</filter>

<filter **>
  @type record_modifier
  <record>
    environment "#{ENV['ENVIRONMENT']}"
    platform "#{ENV['PLATFORM']}"
    application "#{ENV['APPLICATION']}"
    logtype "service.log"
  </record>
</filter>



<match **>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type s3
    <instance_profile_credentials>
    </instance_profile_credentials>
    s3_bucket "#{ENV['COMMON_LOGGING_BUCKET_NAME']}"
    s3_region "#{ENV['REGION']}"
    store_as "gzip"
    acl "bucket-owner-full-control"
    use_server_side_encryption "AES256"
    time_slice_format "%Y.%m.%d"
    path "incoming/%{time_slice}/#{ENV['PLATFORM']}/#{ENV['APPLICATION']}/service.log/"
    s3_object_key_format "%{path}service-%{time_slice}_%{hms_slice}_%{uuid_flush}.%{file_extension}"
    check_bucket false
    check_object false
    <format>
      @type json
    </format>
    <buffer tag,time>
      @type file
      path /fluentd/log
      timekey 5m
      timekey_wait 60s
      chunk_limit_size 50MB
    </buffer>
    <inject>
      time_key "@timestamp"
      time_type string
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ
      localtime false
    </inject>
  </store>
</match>
```